# Apache error 404 and FilesMatch

Tags: regex, apache, http-status-code-404

our server configuration is following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/somepage
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|s?html|css|js)$">
   ErrorDocument 404 default
</FilesMatch>
```

All "not found" pages are redirected to /somepage. If there is "not found" request for image or css or js we redirect request to standard 404 page. This works fine if image is missing in directory that exists eg

If requested file is http://www.domain.com/images/aaa/test.jgp
and exists /*document_root*/images/aaa/ then there is no problem and everything works as expected. Problem appears when aaa/ dir not exist .. then `FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png|s?html|css|js)$"` doesnt work (is not matched) and request is send to http://www.domain.com/somepage .

Is there any way how to match not existing files (gif, jpg, css ..) in not existing directories?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by adding the following

```
 <LocationMatch ".+\.(jpg|png|gif)$">
     ErrorDocument 404 /images/404Image.png
 </LocationMatch>
```

Adding your extensions to the location match regex should work for you as well.